# Assign association for Activerecord model without automatic save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, activerecord, filtering

I'd like to filter a nested association within an API controller and reassign the filtered association afterwards, that just the filtered association will be return from the API.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

parent = Parent.find(1)
most_loved_children = []
# do some filtering
parent.children = most_loved_children # triggers save on each of the children

parent.to_json # should only return parent with most_loved_children
```

Is there a way to "deactivate" the implicit save/updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `most_loved_children` can be collected as sets of attribute hashes, then you can use"

```
parent.children.build( most_loved_children )
```

Which will not do an immediate save.

Comment: Yeah but `parent.to_json` still returns the old attributes

Comment: @schickling you need to stipulate that requirement in your problem statement. The `to_json` method evidently pulls from the saved data, not the active record unsaved data. If that's the case, then your problem may lie in a way to do the `to_json` from unsaved data, not find a way to assign the association without saving it (since that's already known how to do).

Comment: I opened a new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195605/return-filtered-association-with-grape